# How to modify config file from a separate file. Not symlink

Tags: squid

I want to setup squid proxy. Would like to breakup the squid.conf file into two files.
acl.conf
rules.conf
because squid.conf is so large and also easy to make mistake.

I want to have these two files be clean, only contain access-lists and rules and all the changes I make to these to files get pushed to the squid.conf file.

is this possible, and if so, how?

thanks

Comment: edit the squid.conf file.. 
include /etc/squid/conf.d/*

Answer (score 2):

output of `lsb_release -d`

```
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
```

output of `find /etc/squid/ -ls`

```
  2109570      4 drwxr-xr-x   3 root     root         4096 May 30 17:47 /etc/squid/
  2109571      4 drwxr-xr-x   2 root     root         4096 May 30 17:47 /etc/squid/conf.d
  2109572      4 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root          230 May  7 13:21 /etc/squid/conf.d/debian.conf
  2109574    312 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root       316874 May  7 13:21 /etc/squid/squid.conf
  2109573      4 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root         1800 May  7 13:21 /etc/squid/errorpage.css
```

So you can see that the squid package on UBUNTU 20.04 has a `/etc/squid/conf.d/` directory , so **YES** this is possible and recommended .